# Showing that this matrix is nonsingular iff a certain condition on its elements is satisfied

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A_i$ be a $n\times n$ matrix such that $a_{i1} = 1$ and $a_{ij} = x_i^{j-1}$, e.g. $$A_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_1  & x_1^2\\ 1 & x_2 & x_2^2\\ 1 & x_3 & x_3^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

and so on.

I need to show that $\det(A_{15}) \neq 0$ if, and only if, $x_1,\dots, x_{15}$ are all different from each other.

One way is quite direct: if wlg $x_1 = x_2$ then we would have two equal rows so that $\det(A_n)=0$. But I'm stuck trying to show the other way. I wrote down

$$
\det(A_2) = x_2 - x_1,
$$

$$
\det(A_3) = x_1x_2^2 - x_1^2x_2 - x_1x_3^2 + x_1^2x_3 + x_2x_3^2 - x_2^2x_3,
$$

and so on, and I'm seeing quite a pattern but I'm stuck on writing it in a general form so that I could maybe try induction instead. Can someone give me help?

Comment: Hint: you should know that $x_1-x_2$ is a factor of $\det A_3$, since the latter is a polynomial and is zero whenever $x_1-x_2=0$. Similarly you get two more factors. Now what do you get when you multiply these three factors? Can you generalize it from here?

Comment: I'm positive this has been asked here before. Keyword for your search is "Vandermonde determinant."

Comment: Try showing in general that the determinant is the product $$\prod_{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n}(x_i - x_j)$$ (or possibly negative of that). The keyword mentioned in the earlier comment should help you find it.